# LVM - Physical 2 Virtual Recovery of LVM Volume Group

Tags: linux, lvm, raid, software-raid

We have backed up a bare metal server using software RAID and rebuilt it on a VM. Original server is running Oracle Linux 6 (RHEL 6) with Dell Fusion IO software RAID.

BM Server w/ Fusion IO Drives:

```
/dev/fioa--\____ /dev/md127 (Software RAID 1)
/dev/fiob--/
```

VM replica:

```
/dev/sde--\_____ /dev/md127 (Metadisk RAID 1)
/dev/sdf--/
```

LVM Structure on Source:

```
/dev/md127 (PV)
        └─ /vg_ora_data (VG)
                    └─ /lv_ora_datafile (LV)
                           |
                    /dev/mapper/vg_ora_data-lv_ora_datafile -> mounted at /datafile
```

The original server is not lost, this is for DR purposes.

On this md127 raid device, there is supposed to be a VG and LV... then mounted to '/datafile' path.

What is the proper method to recover the LVM volume group and logical volume on the disk once it has been converted from hardware to virtual? The data is there on /dev/md127, and I know that I need to recreate the VG and LV, but documentation varies quite differently out there.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. If the data is there, it should just work. Please elaborate?

Comment: I would not backup the underlying raw disks, but would move the data for a cloud migration.